# Getting the value(x) not defined IN AJAX, web api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This the Javascript code, I am trying to get the listview of reviews to appear when the use clicks on the movie, But in console I am getting an error for second movie and third that Batman is not defined, or Avatar is not defined,but with Anna Karenina( which has a space ) says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Why is this happeninG, I have even encoded the URI in PHP
PHP code

```
 function reviews_get($title=null) { //GET : retrive all the reviews
{
if (!isset($title)){// check if the ID is specified in the URI
    $info->status = 'failure';
            $info->error->code = 11;
            $info->error->text = 'title not specified in URI';
            $this->response($info, 400);
}}
 {  // if the resource exist
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(Title) AS records FROM reviews WHERE Title = "'.$title.'";';
        //$this->response($sql, 200);
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->row();
        if ($data->records == "0") {
            $info->status = 'failure';
            $info->error->code = 12;
            $info->error->text = 'Title does not exist or have a resource';
            $this->response($info, 404);
        }
 }
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT id,Title,review,publisher,rating FROM reviews where Title="'.$title.'";';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
$info->reviews = $data;
$json = json_encode($info);
    //$info->bytes = strlen($json);

$this->response($info, 200);
}
```

Javascript

```
 //Get reviews for a partiluar movie            
          function Getreviewtitle(reviewtitle){
$.ajax({
    url:      "http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/review/reviews/"+reviewtitle,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    $("#allreviews").empty();
    reviewtitle=title;
    console.log(reviewtitle);    
    $.each(data.reviews, function(i,review){
        $('#reviewlist').append('<li><a href="" data-transition="slide" onclick="Getreviewid('+review.id+')"> '+review.Title+' by '+review.publisher+': Rating: '+review.rating+'</a></li>');

    });
    $.mobile.changePage("#allreviews"); //show the results page
    $('#moviereviews').listview('refresh');

    },
error: function (response) {
    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    alert("Message: " + r.error.text);
               }
  });
        }
```

Link to the site if you want to test is :http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/client3/
If you click on reviews at the bottom and then click on the movie that the page I want to display and these ar the codes for it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put quotes around your strings.
For example, you have the following:

```
<a href="#allreviews" data-transition="slide" onclick="Getreviewtitle(Batman)" class="ui-link-inherit">Batman <img src="icon.jpg" onerror="imgError(this);" class="ui-li-thumb" height="150" width="150"></a>
```

Change to:

```
<a href="#allreviews" data-transition="slide" onclick="Getreviewtitle('Batman');" class="ui-link-inherit">Batman <img src="icon.jpg" onerror="imgError(this);" class="ui-li-thumb" height="150" width="150"></a>
```

The way you currently have it, javascript is looking for a variable called batman.

EDIT so it appears you are building the link dynamically, and got confused with your quotes, you have:

```
onclick="Getreviewtitle('+review.title+')">'
```

You need:

```
onclick="Getreviewtitle(\''+review.title+'\')">'
```

Note the extra (escaped) single quote marks

Comment: BuT the quotes are there ` onclick="Getreviewtitle('+review.title+')">`

Comment: @user3051827 Edited to explain

Comment: That has showed a slight change but there are still errors, the page goes blank, and also Still with anna Karenina it is saying that tHE title doesn't exist, is my base 64 encoding in PHP not right?